# How to extract content from .png or .gif files using TIKA?

Tags: png, gif, apache-tika

This is my piece of code:

```
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();     
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

    FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File(
            "resources/bed_bath_beyond.gif"));
    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser);
    parser.parse(inputstream , handler, metadata, parseContext);
    XHTMLContentHandler xhandler=new XHTMLContentHandler(handler, metadata);
    String text = xhandler.toString();
    System.out.println("Contents of the document:" + text);
```

Above code gives OUTPUT:

> Contents of the document:

I am not getting content of the file in output.

Please help.

Comment: What content are you expecting? Do you want to OCR the images?

Comment: Yes OCR the images and the content of the file as well..

Comment: Did you follow the Tika OCR setup instructions? https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaOCR

Comment: Can you please help me to do that?

Comment: Not beyond what's in that document! Follow it, then tell us where you get stuck...